# Can't import ES6 modules from webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have 2 local projects. One of them is a UI library for the second one, but they have to be separate. The second project is an application that should load the UI library from a single file - a bundle the UI library generates - `index.js`

I finished the UI library with a webpack 4 production config like the following:

```
const path = require('path')

const webpackConfig = {
  entry: {
    index: './src/styleguide/main.js',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js/, use: 'babel-loader' },
    ],
  },
  mode: 'production',
}

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

To figure it out, let's use the following as my `index.js`

```
export default function Text () { return <p>Hello world</p> }
```

This yields me a "dist/index.js" file which is also my entry point in `package.json`

---

In the other project which needs to use the UI library, I am trying to do simply `import UI from '../ui/dist/index.js'`

But `UI` is either an empty object `{}` or undefined, or throws Uncaught Error: Minified React error #200; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=200 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

---

I have tried setting `library` and `libraryTarget`, simplifying my scripts down to one liners without dependencies and I am getting very anxious about what I am missing. I would be **grateful** for any help!

Comment: shouldn't you be importing from index.min.js?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe webpack isn't outputting to a module format that you can import from.

Comment: My Bad, I am importing from the correct file. Updating code in config.

Comment: My guess too, but I tried library target var and understanding which is what I used to do in the past

Comment: in your compiled code does it say exports.default = Text or something?

Comment: Nope, Babel did process it and the output is around 3.2kb for a super plain file I provided as an example.

Comment: It sould be exporting something if babel processed it right?

Answer (score 1):

Setting `output.libraryTarget` to `commonjs2` in UI library should solve your problem.

Besides that, you may also want to set react as `peerDependency` in UI libiary and config webpack:

```
externals: {      
    // Don't bundle react      
    react: {          
        commonjs: "react",          
        commonjs2: "react",          
        amd: "React",          
        root: "React"      
    }  
},
```

this can lead to a much smaller bundle.